# Prove $ax \equiv1 \textrm{ mod } 10^k \implies aN(x) \equiv1 \textrm{ mod } 10^{2k}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> For every $a \in Z$, consider the function $N:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$:
> $$N(x)=x(2-ax)$$
> Prove for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that
> $$ax \equiv1 \textrm{ mod } 10^k \implies aN(x) \equiv1 \textrm{ mod } 10^{2k}$$

*Thoughts so far:*
We can make the following computation and find that
$$aN(x)-1 = ax(2-ax)-1=-(ax-1)^2$$
which shows that $aN(x) \equiv1 \textrm{ mod } 10^k$, right? But where does $10^{2k}$ enter the picture?

Comment: Note that if $(ax-1)\mid 10^k$ then $(ax-1)^2\mid 10^{2k}$

Comment: @leoli1 You have the divisibilities reversed. $a\mid b$ means $a$ divides $b\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Of course, you are right (However the idea stays the same)

Comment: By the  linked product rule $\, A\mid B\Rightarrow A^2\mid B^2.\,$ Put $\,A = 10^k,\ B = ax-1\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there:

$$ax-1=10^k q \implies (ax-1)^2=10^{2k} q^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 10^{2k}$$